# Break out of a loop using a method in another module

Tags: python, loops, module

So basically, using exec(), I made an infinitely scaleable list of abilities for my game.  The name of the method for the ability is stored in one module as a string and that string is appended to the header to call the actual method from another module.

Example:

Main module:

```
exec("ptwo." + curboard.tmp[ptwo.position].effect)
```

The effect is assigned by a list in a module

```
effects = ["jump()", "skip(), extra_turn(), none()"]
```

and each item in the list corresponds to a method in another module

```
 def none(self):
        print("This tile has no effect.")
```

So for the extra turn effect i want to make it inject a continue command into the loop so the turn loop starts again from the top.

Just returning continue made it error out.  Ditto with bare continue

Comment: Are all the `effects` methods defined and available to `ptwo`?

Comment: What error did it give when you tried `continue`? Can you include a bit more code to understand how you're trying to do this?

Comment: All the effects are defined and have methods

Comment: It's a "continue outside of loop" error.  I tried both continue and return continue in the method body